# Output elements dynamically based on condition in XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, xslt-2.0

Assume the following xml input...

```
<incidents>
       <incident>
              <year>2011</year>
              <other data here>
       </incident>
       <incident>
              <year>2009</year>
              <other data here>
       </incident>
       <incident>
              <year>2006</year>
       </incident>
</incidents>
```

The xml is always presorted by year so the latest incident year is first. I need to process it using xsl and basically output the data with minimal transform for a 5 years back, max,  but if any years are missing, I just need to output an element for `<incident><year>missingYear</year></incident>`.

So, assuming I had the correct XSL to do this, processing the above xml would produce this...

```
<incidents>
   <incident>
      <year>2011</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2010</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2009</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2008</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2007</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2006</year>
   </incident>
</incidents>
```

I got this far with the xsl, but it's not accounting for large gaps between in years

```
<xsl:variable name="maxYear" select="/incidents/incident/year[1]"></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="incidents" >
  <xsl:element name="incident">           
    <xsl:for-each select="incident">                
      <xsl:variable name="currentYear" select="year"/>              

         <xsl:choose>
           <xsl:when test="($maxYear - (position() -1)) != $currentYear">
             <!-- output the missing year -->
             <xsl:element name="year"> <xsl:value-of select="($maxYear - (position() -1))" /></xsl:element>
             <!-- output the current year node -->
             <xsl:element name="year"> <xsl:value-of select="$currentYear" /></xsl:element>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:element name="year"> <xsl:value-of select="$currentYear" /></xsl:element>             
            </xsl:otherwise>           
         </xsl:choose>                     
    </xsl:for-each>       
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want resulting xml to always contaiin predictable elements (in this case, sequential years, without gaps, even though source document has gaps in years), then why dont you just write it (the resulting xml)? why convert to generate if you know what it needs to be?

i might be exaggerating a little :)

but here's an idea: select the highest and the lowest year values, or first and last. then loop over int values from one end to the other. for each loop iteration lookup the matching element in src xml. if found, generate the rest, otherwise skip.

Comment: I've updated the original question, but now that I think about it, I think you're right....I could get the current year in XSL, then just loop back from their 5 times, each time checking if `year` is available in the source xml, if not, just create the element. Not sure why I made this more difficult on me than required; thanks for enlightening me

Answer (score 2):

**I. Here is a complete XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:param name="pYearsBack" select="6"/>
 <xsl:param name="pThisYear" select="2012"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vEarliest" select=
  "$pThisYear - $pYearsBack"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vYears" select="/*/*/year"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <incidents>
    <xsl:call-template name="genYears"/>
  </incidents>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="genYears">
  <xsl:param name="pTimes" select="$pYearsBack+1"/>
  <xsl:param name="pStart" select="$pThisYear"/>

  <xsl:if test="$pTimes > 0">
   <incident>
     <year>
      <xsl:value-of select=
      "concat($vYears[. = $pStart],
              substring('missingYear',
                         1 div not($vYears[. = $pStart]))
             )
      "/>
     </year>
   </incident>

   <xsl:call-template name="genYears">
    <xsl:with-param name="pTimes" select="$pTimes -1"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="pStart" select="$pStart -1"/>
   </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to be well-formed):

```
<incidents>
    <incident>
        <year>2011</year>
        <other-data-here/>
    </incident>
    <incident>
        <year>2009</year>
        <other-data-here/>
    </incident>
    <incident>
        <year>2006</year>
    </incident>
</incidents>
```

**the wanted, correct result** (all year's incident starting from `$pThisYear` back `$pYearsBack` years) **is produced**:

```
<incidents>
   <incident>
      <year>missingYear</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2011</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>missingYear</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2009</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>missingYear</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>missingYear</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2006</year>
   </incident>
</incidents>
```

---

**II. XSLT 2.0 solution**:

As usual, the XSLT 2.0 solution is much easier, shorter and more readablr:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
 exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pYearsBack" select="6" as="xs:integer"/>
 <xsl:param name="pThisYear" select="2012" as="xs:integer"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vEarliest" select=
  "$pThisYear - $pYearsBack -1"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vYears" select="/*/*/year/xs:integer(.)"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <incidents>
   <xsl:for-each select="1 to $pYearsBack +1">
    <xsl:variable name="vthisYear" as="xs:integer"
         select="$pThisYear - . +1"/>
    <incident>
      <year>
       <xsl:sequence select=
       "($vYears[. eq $vthisYear], 'missingYear')[1]"/>
      </year>
    </incident>
   </xsl:for-each>
   </incidents>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same correct result is produced**:

```
<incidents>
   <incident>
      <year>missingYear</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2011</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>missingYear</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2009</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>missingYear</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>missingYear</year>
   </incident>
   <incident>
      <year>2006</year>
   </incident>
</incidents>
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed info, this is great insight, and will be very helpful on some other problems I have as well, thanks again